Saving Several Webpages as PDF Files in Python
I need to save several webpages as PDF files in Python. I have found several examples in this direction, some uses PyQt5 and and some uses wkhtmltopdf.
I could not be successful with wkhtmltopdf even if I set my environment variables in Windows.
On the other hand, I could save a webpage as a PDF file with PyQt5.
I tried to modify that example to run it in a loop but it did not work. It just saves some of the files but not all.
I need your help regarding this issue with PyQt5 or wkhtmltopdf or in other ways. Here is my code.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPageLayout, QPageSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from pathlib import Path

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


def save_webpage_as_pdf(url, output_file):
    loader = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    loader.setZoomFactor(1)
    layout = QPageLayout()
    layout.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.A4Extra))
    layout.setOrientation(QPageLayout.Portrait)
    loader.load(QUrl(url))
    loader.page().pdfPrintingFinished.connect(lambda *args: QApplication.exit())

    def emit_pdf(finished):
        loader.page().printToPdf(output_file, pageLayout=layout)

    loader.loadFinished.connect(emit_pdf)


catalogue_url = "https://debis.deu.edu.tr/ders-katalog/2023-2024/tr/"
department_url = "bolum_1129_tr.html"
reqs = requests.get(catalogue_url + department_url)
content = reqs.content.decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

urls = soup.find_all('a')
start_index = [url.get('href') for url in urls].index("../havuz/1129tr.pdf")
end_index = [url.get('href') for url in urls].index("bolum_1129_tr.html")
for i in range(start_index + 1, end_index):
    course_url = catalogue_url + urls[i].get('href')
    print(course_url)
    if Path("File(" + str(i) + ").pdf").is_file() == False:
        save_webpage_as_pdf(course_url, "File(" + str(i) + ").pdf")

sys.exit(app.exec_())


What does "but it did not work" mean? Please add detailed error.

@YouHoGeon It just saves some of the files but not all.

The problem is that you're making the application quit as soon as printing is finished. That doesn't happen instantly, because the interaction between IO access and the event loop let some operation continue for some time, but it will eventually quit as soon as it can.
One possible solution is to return the page from the function, and then connect the signal only for the last one. You should also start the application loop only if at least one page is being printed.

def save_webpage_as_pdf(url, output_file):
    ...
    return loader.page()

...
lastPage = None
for i in range(start_index + 1, end_index):
    course_url = catalogue_url + urls[i].get('href')
    path = f"File({i}).pdf"
    if not Path(path).is_file():
        lastPage = save_webpage_as_pdf(course_url, path)

if lastPage is not None:
    lastPage.pdfPrintingFinished.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Still, the above may fail, in case the sizes of the pages are not consistent, or some websites require more time to load: in this case, if the last page is saved before others have even completed loading, the app will close.
For cases like these, using classes is normally preferable, as it allows using a "centralized object" that manages the printing, with a code structure that makes easier to keep track page loading and printing.
Since we don't really need an UI, we can directly subclass the QApplication, and use QWebEnginePage instead of QWebEngineView (there is nothing to show).
class WebPdfPrinter(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, urlList):
        super().__init__(sys.argv)

        self.pageLayout = QPageLayout()
        self.pageLayout.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.A4Extra))
        self.pageLayout.setOrientation(QPageLayout.Portrait)

        self.printers = {}

        for url, path in urlList:
            if url in self.printers:
                continue
            page = QWebEnginePage()
            self.printers[url] = page, path
            page.loadFinished.connect(
                lambda ok, url=url: self.printToPdf(ok, url))
            page.load(QUrl(url))

    def printToPdf(self, ok, url):
        if ok:
            page, path = self.printers[url]
            page.printToPdf(path, self.pageLayout)
            page.pdfPrintingFinished.connect(
                lambda path, success: self.printFinished(success, url))
        else:
            self.printFinished(url)

    def printFinished(self, success, url):
        page, path = self.printers.pop(url)
        page.deleteLater()
        if success:
            print('PDF saved as {}'.format(path))
        else:
            print('PDF failed for {}'.format(url))
        if not self.printers:
            print('Finished, quitting.')
            self.quit()

Note that the above can still be achieved by using simple functions and a global dictionary, but using a class is usually better as it makes expanding it much easier: for instance, you can use the above in a standard GUI program (in that case, subclass from QObject).
In your case, the class above can be used like this:
...
urlList = []
for i in range(start_index + 1, end_index):
    course_url = catalogue_url + urls[i].get('href')
    path = f"File({i}).pdf"
    if not Path(path).is_file():
        urlList.append((course_url, path))

if urlList:
    printer = WebPdfPrinter(urlList)
    sys.exit(printer.exec())


There are three dots in your code.

That's to indicate where your original code goes, without the need to copy all of it again, so that only the relevant changes are highlighted. Besides, ... in Python is a perfectly valid syntax: see Ellipsis.

I might have made something wrong but the modification only gave me File(215).pdf

Have you removed the line in your original code that connected to QApplication.exit()?

Just did it, in that case I only got the files having the indices 130, 156, 200, 202, 205, 208, 211, 215, 217.

It may depend on the complexity of the pages, I assumed they were similar, but if their contents are different (very small and very large pages) that could be a further issue. I'll check the code later and eventually update it. For what's worth, that's why it's generally preferable to use classes and not simple functions: classes allow better object management, and provide a more solid code structure.

I would be very glad if you can teach me using classes on this subject.
